WooCommerce wc_fragment_refresh fragment
I’m trying to figure out how to access the html fragment returned by the min-cart template when retrieved by the WooCommerce wc_fragment_refresh event.
The filter function in this solution isn't firing when the wc_fragment_refresh event is triggered.
Ajaxify custom mini-cart widget in Woocommerce
The cart notices, totals, and quantities are updated, but the filter function isn't executed and the custom attributes in the cart elements are not updated.
I’d like to update several custom attributes in cart items, including the max quantity available.
I’ve added the attributes to an element in a custom mini cart template.
I know I can send second ajax request to retrieve my custom attributes, but I'd prefer to send a single ajax request when cart quantities are updated.
How can I access the fragment returned by the wc_fragment_refresh event, so that I can then update the values in the cart?
Thanks
